# Android - Google Talk Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, google-talk

I am developing an Android application which Google Talk contacts are displayed with their status - this is working fine.

I am not sure which intent should be called to open a chat window using the default Talk app.

- How do I know which Google Talk intents are available to call?
- How do I know which intents are available to call in general?

I am unable to get the following code to work:

```
Uri imUri = new
Uri.Builder().scheme("imto").authority("skype)").appendPath("apactple").build();             
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, imUri); 
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First question:

```
Uri imUri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("imto").authority("gtalk").appendPath("username(e.g.user@googlemail.com)").build();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, imUri);
```

Second question:

```
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo =
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

Comment: Franziskus Karsunke, thank you so much for you answer, i hope it will be helpful alot, let me try then i will come back to you :)..Thanks alot